# ActiveRecord wrong table_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to add an ActiveRecord model called Media. The migration script looks like this

```
class CreateMedias < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def up
      create_table :medias do |t|
         t.string :filename
         t.timestamps null: false
      end
   end
   def down
       drop_table :medias
   end
end
```

This will create a table in my PostgreSQL database called medias just as I expected. My ActiveRecord class looks like this

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

From what I understand this is how it should look like. The name of the ActiveRecord class should in singular and the table name in plural. However, when I try to create a new Media object

```
Media.create filename: "abc.png"
```

I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation    "media" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"media"'::regclass
                                      ^
:           SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"media"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

For some reason ActiveRecord thinks that the table_name should be media and not medias. If I run the same query directly in the database with 'medias' instead of 'media' I get the expected result. For all my other models, the table_name is pluralized but for some reason my Media model is an exception. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Isn't *media* the plural of *medium*?

Comment: Haha, you are absolutely right! My lack of knowledge in english grammar is exposed :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media is a already a plural (it's the plural of medium), so active record pluralizes no further, even if people say "medias" often enough.

You can check how rails pluralizes things from the rails console

```
"medium".pluralize #=> "media"
"media".pluralize #=> "media"
```

If you disagree strongly and don't want to rename your table / model, you can either force active record to use your table name

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "medias"
end
```

or customise the inflections. Your app should have a config/initializers/inflections.rb which sets out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Extending @spickermann's comment, if you want to use `Media` as singular for `medias`, you should provide an inflection to declare it.

file: `/rails_root/config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'medias', 'media'
end
```

This way, you will be able to use this singular/plural relation throughout your whole app..

Comment: Don't forget to renaming all `media` to `medias` which relating to model (Model, Migration, ...). Better is destroying model and regenerating it. Also don't forget to run `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

If you generate model with the name of `Media` like this:

```
rails g model media filename:string
```

then `ActiveRecord` will generate it's table as `media` only not `medias`

Here is it's migration file:

```
class CreateMedia < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :media do |t|
      t.string :filename

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

In your case `ActiveRecord` is looking for `media` and you have defined table name as `medias` that's why you are getting an error.

So you can set table name explicitly in model as:

### Rails >= 3.2 (including Rails 4+):

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "medias"
end
```

### Rails <= 3.1:

```
class Media < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.set_table_name "medias"
end
```

For more details please refer this: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name

---

You can also change the table name by generating new migration file:

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable< ActiveRecord:Migration
   def change
     rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
   end 
 end
```